# Qual é o status da palavra "atraência"?

Tags: etimologia, vocabulário, morfologia

A palavra "atraência" (= atratividade):

- não consta em nenhum dos oito dicionários que consultei,
- não é aceita pelos corretores ortográficos que testei,
- não consta no [Corpus](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org) e
- retorna poucos *hits* relevantes nos buscadores online.

Ou seja, parece ser um erro, e nem sequer um muito comum.

Contudo, por alguma razão sempre a tive como uma palavra cotidiana, correta; os tradutores da Google e da [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator) traduzem corretamente seu significado, e os exemplos de uso na rede podem ser poucos, mas existem (e.g., [1](https://russas.ce.gov.br/destaque/prefeitura-de-russas-trabalha-na-revitalizacao-do-espaco-publico/), [2](https://memoria.ebc.com.br/agenciabrasil/noticia/2012-05-08/ayres-britto-diz-que-%E2%80%9Csaira-campo%E2%80%9D-por-salario-de-juizes), [3](https://www.instagram.com/tv/CI5p85xj1A9/), [4](https://twitter.com/olavoamaral/status/327565255389638656), [5](https://www.diariodasaude.com.br/news.php?article=mulheres-veem-homens-nus-forma-diferente&id=7149), [6](https://www.jusbrasil.com.br/noticias/britto-saira-a-campo-por-salario-de-juizes/3111999), [7](https://notasimpacientes.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/manual-da-sapatao-parte-iii/), PDFs: [8](https://www.teses.usp.br/teses/disponiveis/47/47134/tde-30072010-104834/publico/gaspar_do.pdf), [9](http://sec.sbq.org.br/cdrom/34ra/resumos/T3189-1.pdf), [10](https://www.lume.ufrgs.br/bitstream/handle/10183/8977/000592734.pdf?sequence=1)).

Qual seria o dialeto ou comunidade em que ela é corrente? Ou seu uso seria tão raro, que só se pode classificá-la como erro?

Comment: Para além da resposta que escrevi ainda há outra perspectiva, e.g. os corpos FOLHA/PÚBLICO quando foram compilados tinham o defeito de terem poucos termos técnicos da física e outras áreas porque as fontes eram publicações periódicas generalistas. Se estás à procura de "atraência" no campo científico deves procurar em indices científicos e teses para saber se o termo é usado em universidades...

Comment: À falta de um "dicionário especializado de física, quimica, etc..." a terminologia em português é frequentemente um tradição mantida pelas instituições e sendo que a maioria das publicações são em inglês até nos campos científicos se vê divergência de termos. Por exemplo, a propósito dos morfemas alguns escrevem "morfêmico" enquanto outros "morfemático" o que coloca o problema de haver 2 palavras, ambas pouco usadas, para a mesma coisa... Colocar os autores de um campo de acordo sobre terminologia para uniformizar as coisas também não é fácil portanto pode haver ambiguidade nos termos.

Comment: @bad_coder-onstrike Bom ponto, mas, não, nunca vi "atraência" ser usada no sentido técnico. Interessante o exemplo de morfêmico/morfemático.

Answer (score 3):

Esta análise deve começar pela morfologia, o primeiro passo é tentar reduzir a palavra ao radical mais simples.

Vamos fazer a análise morfológica de ambas as palavras começando pela palavra *atratividade* antes de tentar analisar *atraência*.

#### A. Análise morfológica de atratividade.

1. [**atra**-tividade](https://dicionario.priberam.org/atratividade) (nome feminino) > **atra**-ir (verbo da 3ª conjugação).
2. Vamos ver no dicionário o sentido do radical:

   > [atrair](https://dicionario.priberam.org/atrair)
   >
   > verbo transitivo
   >
   > Origem etimológica: **latim attraho**, -ere.

   Uma das coisas que aqui devemos reparar é o radical ser, pela sua natureza, um **radical verbal** porque para uma coisa ser atraente (adjectivo) tem de atrair em primeiro lugar.
3. O radical verbal **atra-** é indivisivel na morfologia portuguesa. (Reparar que tiramos a vogal temática da 3ª conjugação **-i-** e a desinência do infinitivo **-r** que juntos são **-ir**.)
4. (Aqui vale a pena um parêntesis, podemos espreitar a morfologia do latim e ver que [attraho](https://www.wordsense.eu/attraho/) é **ad- + trahō** transliterado **"a si"- + "puxar"** com o radical simples. Fazemos assim mais uma divisão que não está disponível na morfologia do português e chegamos a um radical indicado como tendo origem no proto-indo-europeu. Ver [traho](https://www.wordsense.eu/traho/#Latin).)
5. **atra-**(ir) > atra-**tiv-o/a** (adjectivo ou nome).

   Aqui evidenciamos o primeiro passo da derivação. Devemos concentrar-nos nas propriedades do sufixo **-tiv-o/a**), que é um sufixo **deverbal** (não pode ser denominal nem deadjectival) e portanto é coerente com a base verbal radical simples. O sufixo forma nomes e adjectivos.
6. **atra-tiv-** o/a > atra-tiv-**idade** (nome feminino).

   Por fim acrescentamos o segundo sufixo e formamos a palavra - é uma **dupla derivação**.

O mais importante para completar a nossa análise é o sufixo **-idade**, este é elencado na literatura linguística como sufixo inteiro (o **-i** inicial é considerado parte integrante do sufixo e não uma *"vogal de ligação"*). É um sufixo que forma nomes deadjectivais - vemos que a classe lexical do produto é de facto um nome e não um adjectivo.

#### B. Análise morfológica de atraência.

**Começamos no ponto 3. da análise anterior sendo que os pontos 1. e 2. seriam iguais para ambos os casos.**

3. **atra**-ência > ????

   Aqui começam os problemas:

   1. Por razão ortográfica e fonética vemos que não existem nem ditongos nem encontros vocálicos **-aê-** em portugês.
   2. **Não existe um sufixo -ência em português!**
   3. Existem 2 sufixos próximos do hipotético **-ência** que seriam:

      - **ncia**- um sufixo que forma **nomes deadjectivais** e escolhe radicais como base.

        Este não está disponivel porque a base não é verbal!
      - **ncia**- um sufixo que forma **nomes deverbais** e **escolhe temas como base**.
4. atra-(ir) > atra **-ê-** ncia

Vamos então começar por verificar a escolha de Tema Verbal pela sufixo. O sufixo **-nica** está indicado na literatura como escolhendo **Temas do Presente**, vejamos o quadro:

|  | 1ª conjugação | 2ª conjugação | 3ª conjugação |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TV infinitivo | dormin **-a** -r | respond **-e** -r | transfer **-i** -r |
| TV passado | dormin **-a** -do | respond **-i** -do | transfer **-i** -do |
| TV presente | dormin **-a -** | respond **-e** | transfer **-e** |

Portanto, vendo as seleção do sufixo, de facto, o Tema Verbal do Presente para verbos da 3ª conjugação é **-e** e temos mais uma razão a reforçar a possiblidade de atra **-ê-** ncia.

Vamos consultar a literatura:

> #### 2.4.1.5 Nomes sufixados em -nci(a)
>
> A forma da base verbal a que -nci(a) se anexa é a do tema do presente, como o revelam os deverbais formados a partir de verbos da 2ª conjugação (proceder/procedência) e de 1ª conjugação (culminar/culminância).
>
> Nos nomes derivados de verbos de tema em **-i-** ocorre uma divergência fonológica relativamente ao expectável, pois verifica-se discrepância entre a VT do verbo base (fluir, gerir, aderir, anuir) e a que ocorre no nome em -nci(a): **-e** (fluênica, gerência, aderência, e anuência). Não é esta razão suficiente para se considerar que o sufixo tem o formato **-enci(a)** . Na realidade estes nomes em correlação paradigmática com os verbos da 3ª conjugação são herdados do latim. Nesta lingua, os verbos que estão na origem dos verbos portugueses **tinham tema em -E- 'breve'**.
>
> in *Gramática Derivacional do Português*, Alexandra Soares Rodrigues, Isabel Pereira, Graça Rio-Torto. Imprensa da Universidade de Coimbra, 2016.
>
> (Negritos meus.)

Vale a pena ler o capitulo acima citado na integra. Tentei numa site de transcrição fonética converter o  [attráhere](https://www.verbix.com/webverbix/go.php?D1=9&T1=attraho) da 3ª conjugação latina -ere (no latim é -are, -ēre, -ere, -ire) e parece que de facto o verbo tem o *"tema em -E- 'breve'"* portanto a única razão que encontro é ortográfica... É possivel que em algum momento da história tenham decidido evitar a escrita do **-aê-** em português o que invalidaria a escrita de *"atraência"*...

---

Por fim, os recursos que citas:

- O [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/now/) é datado entre 2012-2019. Portanto, fosse qual fosse a regra que tivesse retirado *atraência* do vocabulário deve ser muito anterior a isso.
- O DeepL propriamente dito usa técnicas NLP para fazer correspondência entre produtos de derivação provavelmente saltando regras lexicológicas que sejam muito refinadas, sobregeração de resultados.
- O resultado no jusbrasil... Recentemente tive a experiência enriquecedora de conviver com um grupo de advogados brasileiros. Acho que em qualquer sítio onde se fale português a subtileza do que acabamos de descrever é uma quantidade de trabalho pouco razoável para investir numa única palavra, para além disso até a literatura de referência que citei não menciona a problemática particular do **-aê-**.

Considero que a pergunta fica por responder, deixo esta postagem como um subsídio.

Comment: Brilhante subsídio! Sobre o Corpus, também consultei a base histórica, e achei por bem adicionar à pergunta um número maior de exemplos.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146769/discussion-on-answer-by-bad-coder-on-strike-qual-e-o-status-da-palavra-atraen); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.